# Can the return statement in Javascript return multiple things at once?

Tags: javascript, return

I just heard a guy from the Treehouse courses saying that the return statement in JavaScript can't return multiple values at once, the example he gave was:

```
function example() {
var message = "HI";
return 1, message, 'some text';
}
```

I decided to test this myself but instead of using "," I used the "+" operator, and when tested on Google Chrome worked perfect. This is how I tweaked the code:

```
function example() {
    var message1 = ' Hi';
    var message2 = ' How are you?';
    return 1 + message1 + message2 + ' Some text!' + message1.toUpperCase();
}
```

So my question is, Can the return statement behave like this or was simple luck what I did? and is the Threehouse dude right about his statement that "the return statement can't return multiple values at once" ?

Thanks for your help.

PS: I'm new with JS so please try to answer in a non-technical vocabulary if possible! :)

Comment: You are only getting a string back, and not variables. The + operand in JS is to concat strings, that way it works in your return statement.

Comment: Because arrays and objects can hold any datatype in js you could use them to return multiple values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code returns a single value too. To understand it better here is example with just one more line:

```
function example() {
var message1 = ' Hi';
var message2 = ' How are you?';
var mySingleReturnValue = 1 + message1 + message2 + ' Some text!' + message1.toUpperCase();
return mySingleReturnValue
```

}

So all you're doing is concatenating several "values" to a single value which is a string. I guess you should start with learning types in javascript (string, numeric, object, etc.) and basic things you can do with them (add, substract, concatenate, etc.)

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer was to the point of my question! So I think the treehouse dude was wrong! But that's ok, he is trying to teach people how to use JS and i appreciate that!

Comment: I think you got it wrong again. Treehouse dude was right! Return can only be a single value and your example returns a single value! All you're doing is *calculating* that single value in your return statement from several different values. It may appear like you're returning multiple values but you're not. The other side, in example some JS code, that is getting your return value, has no way to determine original values - they are merged/concatendated into one. In example, It cannot know where message 1 ends and where message 2 starts.

Answer (score 3):

Functions, generally speaking, only return one value - but that one value can be a collection of values. In JavaScript you can do this with an object with named properties. In other languages like C# and Python you can use tuples (which serve a similar purpose) - and almost any language will let you return an array (though you lose object type information in that case).

Here is a JavaScript example using an object:

```
function returnMultiple() {
    return { foo: "bar", baz: "qux" };
}

var multiple = returnMultiple();
console.log( multiple.foo );
console.log( multiple.baz );
```

Comment: Well your answer is a little bit confusing for me since I'm still new with JS... But I appreciate the time you took to share your experience with me. I'll have this in mind for a later reference!

Comment: What he means is that you can only return one thing at a time in JS, it's up to your to define what that one thing will be, it could be a single value which can also be a single group of values like a hash or an array.